# Send argument while opening a popup QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to open a popup and pass an argument that will be displayed as part of the popup. I can do that by creating a property and just changing the property right before I open the popup, but I'm wondering if I can accomplish this without making a property and by somehow passing an argument to the popup? Basically accomplish this without creating a property:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 400
    property var username: "Morbius"

    Button {
        text: "Click me"
        onClicked: {
            username = "Definitely not Morbius"
            popup.open()
        }
    }

    Popup {
        id: popup
        width: 220
        height: 200
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
        Text {
            id: name
            text: "Hello, " + username
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Don't use `var` properties unless you need to. Your username property should be a `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need a way to store the value you're passing in, so a property is the natural choice. But I would make the property a part of the Popup, not the parent window. That way you can reuse it in other places too. And you could make it look a little prettier with a custom open() function.

```
Window {
    id: window

    Button {
        text: "Click me"
        onClicked: {
            popup.openMe("Definitely not Morbius")
        }
    }

    Popup {
        id: popup
        property string username

        function openMe(name) {
            username = name;
            open();
        }

        Text {
            id: name
            text: "Hello, " + username
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, why didn't I think of that haha. Thanks for the answer!